# How do I remove the OK/cancel button from the alert dialog

Tags: html, button, dialog, alert

I'm working on a button script for my page.
I want the "OK" button from alert dialogs.
Any Idea on how to do it?

I want the dialog be on the screen until the person refreshes the page.
I'm trying to make it in html5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. You need use a custom dialog.